# Private git HTTPS repo setup on macos

Tags: git, nginx

I'm trying to setup a private `https` git server on my local machine, to be accessed remotely. The machine uses `nginx` as a server (and reverse proxy for other servers).

I must be missing a step since I can't seem to connect to the remote repo. Here's what I've done:

- `nginx` server & domain correctly configured with SSL certificate.
- `.htpasswd` created and configured in `nginx.conf`.
  I can open `index.html` in a browser via `https://git.example.com`, only with the right credentials.
- On the server, in the root directory: `git --bare init test-repo.git`. Directory created with the server user name as the owner, so access permissions should be OK.
- On the client, `git clone https://git.example.com/test-repo.git`. This asks for a user and password, but when I provide them I get: `fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://git.example.com/test-repo.git/'`.

Nginx log says: `open() "/Users/me/server/git/test-repo.git/info/refs" failed (2: No such file or directory)`. I checked on the server (where I ran `git init`), in the `test-repo.git` folder there are, among others, `info` and `refs` folders, but indeed no `info/refs` folder. The `info` folder contains only one file, called `exclude`.

What else needs to be configured for this to work? It's also strange that the server is looking for `/Users/me/server/git/test-repo.git/info/refs` instead of `/Users/me/server/git/test-repo.git/.git/info/refs`. As a quick check, I did `touch index.html` in the above `refs` folder and I can access it perfectly well in a browser over https.

Comment: what do nginx's logs say about those requests?

Comment: Log says: `open() "/Users/me/server/git/test-repo.git/info/refs" failed (2: No such file or directory)`. I checked on the server (where I ran `git init`), in the `test-repo.git` folder there are, among others, `info` and `refs` folder, but indeed no `info/refs` folder. The `info` folder contains only one file, called `exclude`.

Comment: I think that is something you should add into the question as that _is_ relevant information.... I, however, do not have experience in this field so you will have to wait for more knowledgeable people to show up.